# Return newly created TFS work item ID using TFS API?

Tags: c#-4.0, tfs-sdk

Using the TFS API, I am able to create a TFS item, no problem.

What would be the best way for me to know what the Item ID is for the newly created Item?

Thank you,

George

```
        try
        {
            // Authenticate User Account
            NetworkCredential account = new NetworkCredential(USERNAME, PASSWORD, DOMAIN);
            // for user stories from the team project where the user story will be created.
            Uri collectionUri = new Uri(tfsURI);
            //TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri);
            TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri, account);
            WorkItemStore workItemStore = tpc.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
            Project teamProject = workItemStore.Projects[info.TFSProjectName];
            WorkItemType workItemType = teamProject.WorkItemTypes[info.ItemType];
            // Create the work item. 
            WorkItem userStory = new WorkItem(workItemType);
            userStory.Title = info.Title;
            userStory.Description = info.Description;
            userStory.AreaPath = info.AreaPath;
            userStory.IterationPath = info.IterationPath;
            userStory.Fields["Assigned To"].Value = info.AssignedTo;
            if (info.ItemType == "Task")
            {
                userStory.Fields["Discipline"].Value = info.Discipline;
            }
            else if (info.ItemType == "Bug")
            {
                userStory.Fields["Symptom"].Value = info.Symptom;
                userStory.Fields["Steps To Reproduce"].Value = info.StepsToReproduce;
            }
            else if (info.ItemType == "Change Request")
            {
                userStory.Fields["Justification"].Value = info.Justification;
            }
            // Save the new user story.
            userStory.Save();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Error Creating TFS Task.", ex);
            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As soon as you save userStory, the ID field will be populated.  You should be able to just return `userStory.Id`.

Comment: Robaticus, thank you for your answer. It worked perfectly. :)